# Trouble saving serialized form data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Campaign model which I want the user to be able to check off and on a checkbox for each state, which I want to store in an array in one the fields, like `["CA", "NY", "OH", "FL"]`.

I'm not sure if serialized is the correct terminology here. I have some form fields generated like so:

```
<% State::NAMES.each do |state| %>
  <%= check_box("states_allowed", state[1], :checked => true) %>
  <label for="states_allowed_<%= state[1] %>"><%= state[0] %></label>
<% end %>
```

In which `State::NAMES`, is just an array of state names and abbreviations.

So this gives me the HTML of:

```
...
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="states_allowed[NE]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="states_allowed[NE]" id="states_allowed_NE">
<label for="states_allowed_NE">Nebraska</label>
...
```

But how can I save the check fields? The column content stays null and I don't receive an error.

Something I have tried is putting `serialize :states_allowed` in my `Campaign` model, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I add the same problem today, it appears the form isn't properly built in the view.
I simply added at the beginning of my create action:

```
 params[:campaign][:states_allowed] = params[:states_allowed]
```

And it works properly